# Im trying to sort these nodes by alphabetical order

Tags: c++, sorting

```
void PrimaryIndex::sortByTitle(){
    P_Node* temp;
    for (int temp = 0; temp < size(title); temp++) {
        temp = NULL;

        if (temp->title > temp->next->title) {
            swap();
        }
    }
}
```

I know this is wrong, but I'm using nodes for this program. Here is my `PrimaryIndex` header file where the function is declared

```
class P_Node
{
    friend class PrimaryIndex;
private:
    std::string title;
    int pos;
    P_Node * next;
    P_Node * prev;
public:
    P_Node() : title("Hi"), pos(0) { next = prev = NULL; }
    P_Node(std::string my_title, int my_pos) : title(my_title), pos(my_pos)
    {
        next = prev = NULL;
    }
};
```

---

```
class PrimaryIndex
{
    friend class P_Node;
private:
    P_Node * head;
    P_Node * tail;
    int size;
public:
    PrimaryIndex() : size(0)
    {
        head = new P_Node(" ", -1);
        tail = new P_Node("~", -1);
        head->next = tail;
        tail->prev = head;
    }
    // functions that I will be using
    ~PrimaryIndex() { killList(); }
    bool set_title_key(std::string my_title, int my_key);
    void writePrimary();
    void readPrimary();
    void change_title(std::string new_title, int key);
    int matchTitle(std::string inTitle, int key);
    void killList();
    void deletebyTitle();
    void sortByTitle();
    void revSortByTitle();
};
```

I have a lot of these functions implemented and I am trying to get the hang of these nodes. I'm hoping someone could help me out with this

Comment: Is this homework?  If it isn't, use a C++ container class and drop all of this code.  If it is what, exactly is your question?

Comment: how do I sort by title?

Comment: the way I am doing it is incorrect

Comment: One thing you should do is this -- *write down the steps on paper first, before you write any code*.  If you're trying to figure this out by writing the program at the same time, you won't get far.  Do you know what sorting algorithm you will use?  If so, do you know, on paper, how the sort you have chosen works?  If on the other hand, you want a C++ solution without all of the pointer stuff you've written, you will get an answer right away.

Comment: BTW, this isn't to discourage you, but honestly, writing a doubly linked list requires a lot of prep work *before* writing a single line of code.  This means drawing boxes, lines, seeing on paper how the links will work, etc.  Then you need to prepare for the handling of dynamically allocated memory and all the issues involved.  Once you have that, then and only then can you start with the code.  Musing how to implement an aspect of a linked list by writing code and hoping an idea comes along never works out right, believe me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the suggestion of PaulMcKenzie's comment: forget all of your code and use a `std::list`. Its storage type -- a doubly linked list -- is basically what your class is trying to achieve. Then simply use `std::sort`.

```
std::list<std::string> myList{"title1", "title2","titleN"};
std::sort(myList.begin(),myList.end());
```

If that isn't sufficient for you, use your own custom class and pack it in a list, then use `std::sort` with a custom predicate:

```
struct MyClass
{
    std::string title;
    //... more
};
std::list<MyClass> myList;
std::sort(myList.begin(), myList.end()
         , [] (MyClass const& a, MyClass const& b) { return a.title<b.title;});
```